# How to send server metrics data to statsd?

Tags: monitoring, grafana, statsd

Our monitoring stack is Grafana + InluxDB + statsD.

We use it for application monitoring.

We need to add server metrics (CPU, memory, network connections, etc...) to Grafana, so I'm guessing we'll need some agent to collect server metrics and pass to statsD.

Do you know of any agent that can do that? or any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest option for you would be to switch over to using collectd https://collectd.org/, and replace statsd with the statsd plugin for collectd https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:StatsD

Comment: how replacing the statsD with collectD would help me get metrics from servers?

Comment: collectd's primary purpose is to collect system (cpu, load, memory, disk, etc) stats from servers and report them to a tsdb.  You can read more at https://collectd.org/

Comment: So collectD will send the data to...?

Comment: Right, sending the data from collectD to influxDB makes a whole lot sense than just changing statsD.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://my-netdata.io.

It can monitor a ton of things, it is a statsd server by itself, it can visualize all metrics by itself and can push all metrics to graphite, opentsdb, prometheus, influxdb, etc.

Free and open source: GPL v3+.

EDIT: it also allows you to send statsd metrics from shell scripts: https://github.com/firehol/netdata/wiki/statsd#sending-statsd-metrics-from-shell-scripts